# Numpy: Loading data from JSON file gives np array with nested lists

Tags: python, json, numpy

I am loading data from a JSON file as list and then making a NumPy array.

The JSON file is structured as follows

```
{
    "label": "4",
    "mfcc": [
        [
            [
                -147.2358550730904,
                52.60503152410914,
                <more values Total=13>

            ],
            <more arrays Total=44>
```

The code I am using to make a NumPy array using data collected from the JSON file

```
with open("data.json", 'r') as file:
   data = json.load(file)
   
   mfcc = np.array(data["mfcc"])
```

It seems that the most outer list gets converted to a NumPy array while the inner lists are still lists. See the image below:

[image: Image showing datatypes]

What has happened?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A JSON string/file can be a combination of nested lists and dicts.  You don't show any of file or the list after loading.  `np.array(alist)` will give a nice multdimensional array only if the nesting in the list is regular (as shown in `numpy.array` docs.  So just saying that the file is JSON doesn't help us help you.

Comment: I have added in a snippet of the JSON file

Comment: `data["mfcc"]` does look like a list, but it may not be regular enough to turn into a multidimensional array.

Comment: The list was irregular. I added a condition in the code that made the JSON file to deal with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it means the file contains a numpy array with lists inside.

- Either is was made on purpose
- Either you (or someone) tried to convert a list of list into a numpy array but the nested lists are not all with the same length (which is required for a numpy array). Therefore, numpy doesn't create a proper 2D numpy array but a 1D numpy array with lists inside. To fix it, make sure all the nested lists are the same length (you can pad them with `0` for instance)

Comment: The second point does not hold.The data in the JSON file is complete

Comment: Rechecked the JSON file. Missing values was the imposter. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found the issue. Please don't forget to validate the answer or add the answer to your question for the future readers